# Block field to referene a view

Tags: views, blocks, entities, 8

I am struggling to find a way for a custom block type of mine to reference a view. Basically I want a field of the block to show some of the newest articles.

Using the entity reference field and an entity reference view I must select the articles to show manually.

Is there a simple way to use the entity reference field to render the contents of a view or a view block? Or do I need to code it myself?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a views block directly? Core has no formatter to display a referenced view like a view, but I'm not sure why you need that indirection in the fist place, given that this is a view which can create blocks out of the box.

Comment: Basically I have a page which consists of blocks only, let us call it sections. So each section has different fields, some of them need to show a list of newest nodes of a specific node type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield to reference views and even pass arguments.

Comment: This is a D8 question, that module has no D8 release. But yes, it will need a module like that.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed the D8 tag.

Comment: The sandbox of the Viewfield D8 version is here: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/pferlito/2409263. But against D8rc3 it's broken ...